Power Apps Collect
Is the "Collect" function supposed to work on tables in Dataverse? I saw a video where it works with an Excel data source, but in my app collect stores collections but it doesn't insert them into my tables, I have to use "Patch", am I missing something?

Do you get any errors when trying to use Collect to add records to a Dataverse table? If so, can you say what those are?

You are not missing anything, it is like it work. You have to use the Patch to get data from Collection to Dataverse, It is actually a matter of realization that what we can do and how  it can be done in Power Apps. Check this link and it has very god video explaining  saving data from collection to Dataverse Table. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-apps/maker/canvas-apps/create-update-collection
